# How to convert a grayscale image to binary in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, binary, grayscale

I have to write a program that converts intensity images into black-and-white ones. I just figured I could take a value from the original matrix, I, and if it's above the mean value, make the corresponding cell in another array equal to 1, otherwise equal to zero:

```
for x=1:X
    for y=1:Y
        if I(x,y)>mean(I(:))
            bw(x,y)=1;
        elseif I(x,y)<mean(I(:))
            bw(x,y)=0;
        end
    end
end
image(bw)
```

Unfortunately, the image I get is all black. Why?

I is in `uint8`, btw. 2-D Lena.tiff image

Comment: uint8 means that white would be 255, not 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `imagesc(bw)` (instead of `image(bw)`). That automatically scales the image range.

Also, note that you can replace all your code by this vectorized, more efficient version:

```
bw = double(I>mean(I(:)));
```

Answer (score 8):

Use this :

```
bw = im2bw(I, graythresh(I));
```

Here the documentation for [im2bw](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2bw.html);

using `imshow(I,[]);`, doesn't evaluate the image between 0 and 255, but between `min(I(:))` and `max(I(:))`

**EDIT**

You can change `graythresh(I)` by anyother level. You can still use the mean of your image. (Normalize between 0 and 1).

```
maxI = max(I(:));
minI = min(I(:));

bw = im2bw(I,(maxI - mean(I(:)))/(maxI - minI));
```

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that you are always using the `mean` untill then.

What you will want to do is do this before the loop:

myMean = mean(I(:));

And then replace all following occurences of `mean(I(:))` by `myMean`.

Using the running mean as you currently will definitely slow things, but it will not be the reason why it becomes all black.

Comment: What distiortion do you mean? `I` is not being overwritten. It's of course inefficient, but it's not a running mean; `mean(I(:))` is the same value every time

Comment: @LuisMendo You are right, in that case my point is less important. Have edited my answer.

Comment: Finding mean before made it MUCH faster.